# check the value is in the array key

Tags: php, arrays

I have the value 'Target' which I want to check it is in the array `Array ( [Target] => Prospects, [Contacts] => Contacts ,[Leads] => Leads )`

I want to check the given value is in array key and get the value of the key ie, for `Target` expected to get `Prospects`

I have tried as

```
<?php
$test=Array ( 'Target' => 'Prospects', 'Contacts' => 'Contacts', 'Leads' => 'Leads' );
if(in_array('Target',$test))
{
    echo 'True';
}
else{
    echo 'False';
}

?>
```

but getting false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple php functions that can do the job, listing out few.

```
<?php
$test=Array ( 'Target' => 'Prospects', 'Contacts' => 'Contacts', 'Leads' => 'Leads' );
if (array_key_exists('Target', $test)) {
    echo 'True';
} else {
   echo 'False';
}
```

if you want to check both key and value pair you can use directly

```
if (isset($tests['Target']) && $tests['Target'] == 'Prospects') {
   echo 'True';
}
```

another way will be using array_intersect

```
<?php
$test=Array ( 'Target' => 'Prospects', 'Contacts' => 'Contacts', 'Leads' => 'Leads' );
$test1 = ['Target' => 'Prospects'];
$result = array_intersect($test, $test1);
if ($result == $test1) {
   echo true;
}
?>
```

if you want to check if key is exists and retrieve the value use

```
if (isset($tests['Target']) {
    echo $tests['Target'];
}
```

Comment: ... _and get the value of the key_

Comment: @jibsteroos if you want to get value of the key, you have key in array get it like $arr['key'] and if you want to search use array_search('value', $arr)

Comment: _I_ don't want to get the value, the OP wants it

Comment: `is_set()` does not exist - see [isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)